# how to solve Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, string given in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, eloquent

In **postman** when I send this link `/api/bonus?provider=[Company_A]`, what my expected result is to display all the data that with **Company_A** provider. 
In my table, the provider is a JSON format and there are `[Company_A,Company_B,Company_C,Company_D]`

But what I'm getting is this error

> "Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the
>   type array, string given

**My controller**

```
    public function all(Request $request)
    {
        $size = $request->input('size');

        $bonus = Bonus::with('bonusCompany');

        $bonus = Filter::apply($request, $size, $bonus);
}
```

**My Filter**

```
public static function apply(Request $filters, $size, $bonus_list)
    {
      if ($filters->has('provider') && $filters->input('provider') != "") {
                $bonus->whereHas('bonus', function ($query) use ($filters) {
                    $query->whereIn('providers', $filters->input('provider'));
                });
                echo  $filters->input('provider');
        }
}
    // Get the results and return them.
    return $bonus->paginate($size);
```

Comment: What does `$filters->input('provider')` contain? If it's a string, then you need to create an array, such as `[$filters->input('provider')]`.

Comment: It contain `[Company_A]`

Comment: Can you show `var_dump($filters->input('provider'));`?

Comment: Both `[Company_A]` and `[Company_A,Company_B,Company_C,Company_D]` are not valid json strings. The values should be between `"`.

Comment: the result is `string(11) `

Comment: Since it's in json_format, you need to use use json_decode when you pass it into the whereIn function, so that it turns into an array

Comment: @Jerodev so I should call like this? `/api/bonus?provider=["Company_A"]` ?

Comment: @aynber can you show me how please?